# What's wrong with this code? When I open the dev tools in chrome it's saying function out is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code! I've created a table and a form. My objective here is to input the number in the input box and it'll automatically outputs the value according to the table. But the function which I've created is not working.

```
<!--body-->
        <div id="table"> <!--Table creation-->

            <table border=1> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Range From 1..10</td>

                    <td>$300</td>    
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Range From 10..20</td>

                    <td>$200</td>    
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td>Range From 20..30</td>

                    <td>$100</td>    
                </tr>      
            </table>   

        </div>


        <br>
        <div id="input">
            <form>
            <label name="Unit" for="input">Units</label>
            <input text="text" name="value" id="value" oninput="out()">
            <input text="text" name="output" id="output">
            </form>
        </div>    


        <script> //scripting
            function out()
            {
                var x=document.getElementById("value").value;
                var y;
                if(x>=1 && x<=10)
                {
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHtml="$300";
                }

                else if(x>10 && x<=20)
                {
                   document.getElementById("output").innerHtml="$300";
                }

                else{
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHtml="$300";
                }
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works as is for me. When I add `console.log("Hello from function");` as the first line of code in the function and then type in the first textbox, the message appears in the console.

Comment: Looks fine on my fiddle also

Comment: I've checked this on jsfiddle as well

Comment: Your posted code is working, if is not working for you is because you have a different code than posted. And you are bad downvoting all answers indiscriminately

Comment: @GuillermoSubiran I'm not downvoting lemme just upvote all the posts

Comment: @InkoHagoed ah ok sorry, I will quit my downvote

Answer (score -1):

Try moving your function above your html. It could be that the browser is trying to execute the function before it is loaded.

Comment: Functions in JavaScript can be called prior to their declaration due to hoisting.

Answer (score -1):

You will have a second problem if you can run the function it will still not give an output to the field... But for the first question i have no answer....

Just try `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` because it is an input-field and not a normal HTML Tag.

Comment: All `input` elements have a `value` property. This is the property to read when you want to get what's been entered into the element.

Comment: Yeah sure but he is trying to do that look at his code he selects exactly this element... Could you please remove the downvote?

Comment: Ah, you are correct about that, sorry. But, your answer doesn't actually address the issue.

Comment: Yep i just saw that im sorry :)

Answer (score -1):

please try this code

```
function out()
        {

            var x=document.getElementById("value").value;
            var oTrs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var index = 0;
            for(var i = 0;i<oTrs.length;i++){
                var arr = oTrs[i].children[0].innerHTML.replace('Range From ','').split('..');
                var num1 = arr[0]-0,
                    num2 = arr[1]-0;
                if(x>num1 && x<=num2)
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }else{
                    index = oTrs.length - 1;
                }
            }

            document.getElementById("output").value = oTrs[index].children[1].innerHTML;
        }
```

Comment: That's not the reason why he is getting the error that he is talking about though.

Comment: You've rewritten the function that was already working with another that has many changes without explaining what you did and how it would help solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The `out()` function that you posted looks ok, but maybe you have any other version of that function with any `console.log` or something else between `if` and `else if` statements that makes out() function fails. I noticed the unnecessary line breaks between those statements and maybe there is something else not in your example code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--body-->
        <div id="table"> <!--Table creation-->

            <table border=1> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Range From 1..10</td>

                    <td>$300</td>    
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Range From 10..20</td>

                    <td>$200</td>    
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td>Range From 20..30</td>

                    <td>$100</td>    
                </tr>      
            </table>   

        </div>


        <br>
        <div id="input">
            <form>
            <label name="Unit" for="input">Units</label>
            <input text="text" name="value" id="value" oninput="out()">
            <input text="text" name="output" id="output">
            </form>
        </div>    


        <script> //scripting
            function out()
            {
                var x=document.getElementById("value").value;
                console.log('x: ',x);
                var y;
                if(x>=1 && x<=10)
                {
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHtml="$300";
                }
                console.log('y: ',y);//you have something here?
                else if(x>10 && x<=20)
                {
                   document.getElementById("output").innerHtml="$300";
                }

                else{
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHtml="$300";
                }
            }
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The OP isn't asking about a failing function. He's saying that he's getting a "function not defined" error.

Comment: Sure, run my code and type something in any input field and you will get your "Uncaught ReferenceError: out is not defined".

Comment: Actually, the error is : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else" and you get this error immediately. If that was what the OP was getting, he'd know right away what the issue was.

Comment: @InkoHagoed you don't understood your own code... The code that you posted is working, check it out in any fiddler. You can't go downvoting all answers for your mistake

Comment: I down voted all the answers because none of them address the issue that the OP is having. And, in each I explained why.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes the main error is the syntaxError, but when you type in any input you got the "out is not defined" I'm saying that I think in the posted code is missing something pice of code, who add  line breaks between if / else if?

Comment: hey guys I'm not downvoting any posts.

Comment: @GuillermoSubiran I understand and what I'm telling you is that if your suggest was the issue, then the OP would be getting an entirely different error before he got the one he's asking about. The first error would clearly indicate what the issue was.

Comment: @ScottMarcus hey scott upvote all the posts coz all of them are blaming me for there useless code and answers

Comment: @InkoHagoed Only one person is blaming you and I have said that you are not the one down voting. I won't change my votes because the answers are all wrong.

Comment: @GuillermoSubiran line breaks are in html not j.s please read carefully.

Comment: @InkoHagoed sure I'm no talking about <br> tags. I'm talking about the line breaks in the js code between "if" and "else if". You understand?